# Is change in momentum over time equal to average force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum

Hi guys I’m trying to get my head round some basic physics I understand the change in velocity x mass = change in momentum

Using this does change in momentum/ time = Mass x acceleration as velocity/time = Acceleration

So my understanding from this is will we get an average force? As F=ma ?

Comment: It is not an average if you use derivatives

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If my comment to the answer below somehow relates to your question please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, let us analyse this question.

What we know is that `p = mv (p being momentum, m being mass and v being velocity)`

So, $$\frac{p}{t} = \frac{mv}{t}$$

Which is, $$\frac{p}{t} = m(\frac{v}{t})$$

Now, $\frac{v}{t} = acceleration$
$$\frac{p}{t} = ma$$

As you said, F = ma $$\frac{p}{t} = F$$

Which is $$\Delta p = F$$

So `yes`, change in momentum is equal to the average force ( $\Delta p = F$ )

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting symbols and equations.

Comment: I'm a real no-math-man and I wonder how the delta comes in so suddenly. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The changes (differences) you mention should really be *differentials*, so replace $\Delta p=\Delta (mv)$ with:

$$\mathrm{d}p=\mathrm{d}(mv)$$

which for constant mass $m$ becomes:

$$\mathrm{d}p=m\mathrm{d}v$$

Similarly:

$$a=\frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}=m\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$$

becomes:

$$a(t)=m\frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{d }t}$$

Replacing the $\Delta$ with $\mathrm{d}$ means we shift from averages to instantaneous changes, used in Calculus to compute ever changing quantities like $a(t)$.  Only if quantities like $v$ are independent of time $t$ can differences $\Delta v$ be used accurately.

Read more on the differences between $\Delta$ with $\mathrm{d}$ [on my relevant webinar](http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=65532#pid441317).

Comment: Thanks guys so excuse me for being naive but what is the delta for?

Comment: Hi Jack. $\Delta$ stands for 'difference'. E.g. $\Delta x=x_2-x_1$

Comment: The following would make up some new question ? Does a perfect elastic-collision know no time, no delta? If two perfectly  equal masses  of perfectly equal velocities collide there is only an exchange of direction (momentum is a vector). This constellation "knows no time"? There is only exchange of direction, and there cannot be applied a delta of momentum as this "refraction" just happens? I think about "elastic refraction" of photons.